# Having trouble with .9999.. =1 in calculus

Tags: calculus, limits

the issue I have with the assumption is,when I encountered this problem what is $$\lim\ _{x\to \infty} \left[1 -\frac1x\right]^{-x}$$

I thought it would be 1 but the answer is $e^{-1}$ ,how ?

my reasoning is $\frac1x$ will be very small and 1 minus a very small number would be .99999...  which is more or less equal to 1 and 1 raised to the power of a large number would also be 1.

**Edit:**

ok I guess i need to elaborate a little bit, I want to see where my intuition is failing so I'll try and break my up assumptions and can anyone point out where i'm going wrong

1) if x is a large number $\frac1x$ will be very very small

2) 1 minus a very small number is .999.. repeating or not ?

3) if 1 and 2 are right then it must be equal to 1 right ?

and sorry if I'm a little dumb.. try to bear with me guys :)

**Edit 2**
the link given in the comment seemed to help ,the second answer.Thanks @jyrki-lahtonen
[Solve a seemingly simple limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n-2}n\right)^{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336747/solve-a-seemingly-simple-limit/336781#336781)

**Edit 2**
found this video which explains the exact problem .. :)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAv5pahIevE&list=SPBE9407EA64E2C318&index=10

Comment: This is very nearly the definition of $e$. But to address your concern: You are raising a number less than $1$ to an infinite power so your intuition is likely to break down.

Comment: Your reasoning is not good enough. If $u<1$ then the higher power you take $u$ to, the closer you get to $0$, so there are two opposing heuristics, one which favors a limit of $1$ and the other a limit of $0$ (or $\infty$ since it is $-x$ rather than $x$ in the exponent). More solid logic is needed. Note that, one definition of $e$ is that limit (sans the minus signs). What you want to know is how it is equivalent to the other two main definitions (sum of reciprocals of factorials, $y(1)$ for the solution to the initial value problem $y'=y$, $y(0)=1$).

Comment: Note that the answer is $e$, not $e^{-1}$.

Comment: If you want to "test" it, plug in a very big value of $x$ in $(1-1/x)^{-x}$, this might give you some intuition.

Comment: two $x$ go to infinity at the same time instead of on their own

Comment: See [this closely related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/336747/11619) for more discussion.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JyrkiLahtonen of all the explanations yours helped me .the other seemed a little mathy to me.Im relearning math tyring to get the meaning of things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This a common mistake: you shouldn't pass to the limit in just one part of the expression and leave the other part pending, in fact we have
$$\left(1 -\frac1x\right)^{-x}=\exp\left(-x\log\left(1 -\frac1x\right)\right)$$
and notice that the function $x\mapsto-x$ diverges to $\infty$ and $x\mapsto\log\left(1 -\frac1x\right)$ is convergent to $0$ but their product is convergent to $1$ so if  you just pass to the limit for the last function you *kill* the contribution of the first function for the  limit.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left(1 - {1 \over x}\right)^{-x}
=
{\rm e}^{-x\ln\left(1\ -\ 1/x\right)}\
\overbrace{\quad\to\quad}^{x\ \to\ \infty}\
{\rm e}^{-x\left(-1/x\right)} = {\rm e}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim\ _{x\to \infty} \left[1 -\frac1x\right]^{-x} = y$$
taking $\log$ on both sides
$$\lim\ _{x\to \infty} -x\log\left[1 -\frac1x\right] =\log(y)$$

therefore the limit changes to
as$x\to\infty$
$$log(y)=1 \to y=e  $$